# Retrieving data from formatted string in Bash

Tags: bash, unix

I am looking for an easy way to get some numeric parameters from a string.

Consider having a string like: `W400Y345655T23`. From this string I need to get: `W=400`, `Y=345655` and `T=23`.

The number of parameters to retrieve is always the same (3 in the example: `W`, `Y` and `T`). Names of parameters also remain constant. But the number length can differ for each numeric value (I can have `W10Y34T334` but also `W100000Y2T90`). Also, parameters appear in the same order.

Using Bash, is it possible to solve this using some sort of fancy `scanf` or `String.Format` equivalent way? Thankyou

Comment: Do parameters appear in the same order? Also your `W100000Y2Y90` has two `Y` and no `T`, is this correct?

Comment: Yes, same order, posting this detail...

Comment: How about @fedorqui's second question?: 'Also your `W100000Y2Y90` has two `Y` and no `T`, is this correct?'

Comment: @damienfrancois: SOrry for the mistake, fixed it. Well fedorqui's answer is good, but looks like BASH regex (something I did not know about) looks more reliable and flexible...

Comment: Not sure what you mean with 'flexible', but it's your call :)

Comment: @damienfrancois: By flexible I mean that it is possible to change parameters name for example and the approach is more compact. If variable change positions fedorqui'as approach fails. But I do know, I told everyone variables are not supposed to change... but using Bash Regex I also get this feature, not required but still something more, that's all! fedorqui's answer is really valuable!

Comment: @Andry: oops misread Fedorqui for Alfe. Disregard my latest comment. I was not referring to Fedorqui's answer, only his question in the comment of your question. And I thought you were discussing Alfe's answer (which is similar to mine, and flexible as well, but does not use Bash Regex :) )

Comment: @damienfrancois: regarding Alfe's one... looks interesting...

Comment: @Andry `If variable change positions fedorqui'as approach fails.`??? What did you try?

Comment: @fedorqui: Yes, I did try that and what I said was not correct. I now realize I was wrong... I am trying again your approach...

Comment: @Andry no problem, just wondering what can be wrong.

Comment: @fedorqui: No, I like your approach now more than Bash Regex... looks simpler... just trying to place stuff into variables in one shot with process subst...

Comment: Well my approach was to be printed, not to be used. anubhava's solution is very good and I really like @damienfrancois 's one. All together now you have many options to work with :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using BASH regex:

```
s='W400Y345655T23'
[[ "$s" =~ ^W([0-9]*)Y([0-9]*)T([0-9]*)$ ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}, ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}, ${BASH_REMATCH[3]}
```

**OR to get values into BASH variables:**

```
read W Y T < <([[ "$s" =~ ^W([0-9]*)Y([0-9]*)T([0-9]*)$ ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} ${BASH_REMATCH[2]} ${BASH_REMATCH[3]})

>echo $W
400
>echo $Y
345655
>echo $T
23
```

Comment: Hard to place the result in variables this way.

Comment: Yep, through the backdoor, but working.  I like the use of `=~` and `BASH_REMATCH`, thus ⁺¹.

Comment: @Ashish: Sure I can explain. `=~` BASH operator is used for regex matching so here `W400Y345655T23` is matched against regex: `^W([0-9]*)Y([0-9]*)T([0-9]*)$` Each group inside parentheses is available in a BASH array called `BASH_REMATCH`. This command then echoes each element of `BASH_REMATCH` which is read using `read W Y T` and values are available in BASH variables `W, Y and T`

Comment: @anubhava: Sorry I have problems when using the second version. Looks like there is some problem using operator <... is it ok to have two < < separated by a space?

Comment: Its a re-director.. don't use space I think

Comment: @anubhava: Ok, no sorry, no problem, mistyped some stuff... btw I do not understand the usage of < <... Could you please explain? thanks in advance

Comment: << means you are giving output of right to left as input
& >> means you are giving output of left to right as input

Comment: here Anubhava is storing values from his command into bash variables

Comment: @anubhava : Lot of stuffs to be learned from you. Thanks and my 1 upvote already to you

Comment: @Andry: Yes `< <(...)` is indeed the right syntax. It is called process substitution where read is accessing command's (in parentheses) output and setting BASH variables.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use an associative array:

```
declare -A x
eval x=($(echo "W400Y345655T23" | sed 's/\([A-Z]\)/ [\1]=/g'))
```

Accessing the variables then is straight forward:

```
echo ${x[W]}
```

etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
$ eval $( sed 's/\([A-Z]\)/ \1=/g' <<< W400Y345655T23 )
$ echo $W $Y $T
400 345655 23
```

It will work with any number of distinct one-capital-letter parameter name, in any order.

Comment: even shorter than mine.  ⁺¹ :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a workaround using `grep -Po` to match numbers and chars:

```
$ echo "W400Y345655T23" | grep -Po '\d*'
400
345655
23

$ echo "W400Y345655T23" | grep -Po '[A-Z]*'
W
Y
T
```

If you save these results into a variable:

```
c=$(echo "W400Y345655T23" | grep -Po '[A-Z]*')
d=$(echo "W400Y345655T23" | grep -Po '[0-9]*')
```

Then you can print in columns like this:

```
$ paste -d= <(echo "$c") <(echo "$d")
W=400
Y=345655
T=23
```

With this solution is that you can have any group of numbers / letters, and also can be different than `W`, `Y`, `T`.